# Symfony CollectionType: Merge new entries

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-3.2

My symfony form represents an entity `Mail` which has a one to many relation with another entity called `Attachment`. Therefore, the `MailType` form contains a `CollectionType` field for embedding its `AttachmentType` forms:

```
$builder
    ->add('attachments', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => AttachmentType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => false,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ]);
```

My view will only send new attachments to my Symfony backend. So when storing the form data into the database, I only want to add new attachments of the mail and do not touch any existing attachments.

Unfortunately, Symfony / Doctrine behave differently: If `n` attachments are contained in the form data then `n` first existing  attachments are overwritten by those new attachments:

```
existing attachments (in DB): [old1, old2, old3]
new attachments (contained by HTTP request): [new1, new2]
desired result in DB: [old1, old2, old3, new1, new2]
actual result in DB: [new1, new2, old3]
```

How can I achieve this? I thought `by_reference => false` will cause the `addAttachment` method to be called, so I also expected this to work out-of-the-box.

My `Mail` entity code:

```
class Mail {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Attachment", mappedBy="mail", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $attachments;

    ...

    public function addAttachment(\AppBundle\Entity\ttachment $attachment) {
        $attachment->setMail($this);
        $this->attachments[] = $attachment;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

My controller code processing the form:

```
    // $mail = find mail in database
    $form = $this->createForm(MailType::class, $mail);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $mail = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($mail);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the ArrayCollection way of adding? Like: $this->attachments->add($attachment);

Comment: And are you instantiating $attachments as a new ArrayCollection() in the constructor?

Comment: Doesn't `'by_reference' => false` cause Symfony to call `$this->attachments->add($attachmetn)`? Yes I instantiated $attachments as new ArrayCollection in the constructor. Sorry I missed that above

Comment: You have '$this->attachments[] = $attachment;' try to use the ArrayCollection method '$this->attachments->add($attachment);' I don't think it is called automatically, no.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do what you want. The simplest would be to give empty data or new attachment entities to your form field:

```
$builder
        ->add('attachments', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => AttachmentType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'data' => [new Attachment()] // or add more or []
        ]);
```

Then in your Mail entity:

```
public function addAttachment(Attachment $attachment) {
    $attachment->setMail($this);
    $this->attachments[] = $attachment;
    return $this;
}

public function removeAttachment(Attachment $attachment) {
    return $this;
}
```

If you are using **removeAttachment** for some other functionality and you want to actually remove the Attachment, you can take advantage of the **property_path** settings of the form field:

```
'property_path' => 'appendAttachments'
```

and create **addAppendAttachment** and **removeAppendAttachment**:

```
public function addAppendAttachment(Attachment $attachment) {
    $attachment->setMail($this);
    $this->attachments[] = $attachment;
    return $this;
}

public function removeAppendAttachment(Attachment $attachment) {
    return $this;
}
```